# SQL concatenating with python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, sql-update

I am trying to update my mysql database field with a concatenation. I have to read my file line by line, and i need to append the existing string with the loaded line. I have to do it like this because my goal is to insert a 3gb long whitespace separated text file into one longtext field, and mysql only capable of handling 1gb text to insert.

The problem with my code is that if i add the field name to the concat function like `seq=concat(seq, %s)` I get a SQL syntax error, but when I add the field name as a variable, python acts like it's a string.

So short story long with this input file:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I want to have an updated mysql field like this:
`aaabbbccc`

But I get this: `seqccc`

Any idea how should i work with the fieldname to get this work?

```
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='sys',
                                         user='Pannka',
                                         password='???')

cursor = connection.cursor()
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        sql = "update linedna set seq=concat(%s, %s) where id=1"
        val=('seq', line.rstrip())
        print(line.rstrip())
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        connection.commit()

cursor.close()
connection.close()
f.close()
print(0)
```

Comment: Parameterization is for string literals not identifiers such as table or column names.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want:

```
sql = "update linedna set seq = concat(seq, %s) where id=1"
val=(line.rstrip())
cursor.execute(sql, val)
connection.commit()
```

This will append each new line at the end of the already existing database value in column `seq`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i want to do, but it's give me an sql syntax error.
`Traceback:
  cursor.execute(sql, val)
  (...)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s) where id=1' at line 1`